# How to set cookies for visit method in rspec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

I am trying to set cookies before visiting home page in rspec.

```
cookies[:authentication_token] = token
```

if I use `get root_path`, I receive the cookies in the controller. cookie is not passed when using `visit root_path`.

How can I pass cookies with `visit` method?

Comment: Do you use [capybara](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara) with your rspec?

Comment: So why you set cookies with function? If you can login with web page, I think you should test login function with click login button and fill in you account then test if login.

Comment: I am using google plus oauth provider to login. I am not sure how to test that. In order to test the websites other functionality, I am setting the cookie manually.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to set the token

```
headers = {}
Rack::Utils.set_cookie_header!(headers, :user_authentication_token, token)
cookie_string = headers['Set-Cookie']
Capybara.current_session.driver.browser.set_cookie(cookie_string)
```

found it here http://makandracards.com/makandra/15183-cucumber-step-to-set-cookies-in-your-capybara-session